# Absolute Value Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$x^3+|x| = 0$$
One solution is $0.$ We have to find the other solution (i.e, $-1$)

$$Solution:$$
CASE $1$:
If $x<0,~|x| = -x$, we can write $x^3+|x| = 0$ as $-x^3-x=0$
$$x^3+x=0$$
$$x(x^2+1)=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow x=0, or, x=\sqrt{-1}$$
Please tell me where I've gone wrong.

Comment: I don't think there should be a minus in front of the $x^3$

Comment: $\;|x|=-\;$ , for $\;x<0\;$ ...but $\;x^3\;$ remains the same.

Comment: The conclusion of case 1 doesn't make sense: The hypothesis of that case is $x < 0$, but one of the solutions isn't even real. (In fact, if one is counting complex solutions, one should have both of $\pm i$.)

Comment: Because it is given $\;x^3\;$ !! The only thing you do is to **apply** the definition of $\;|x|\;$ , **all the rest** remains exactly the same as it was given...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints:

Suppose

$$\begin{align}&x\ge 0\implies 0= x^3+x=x(x^2+1)\;\ldots\\{}\\&x<0\implies0= x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=\ldots\end{align}$$

All in all, there are two different *real* solutions.

Comment: But for the second case, why didn't you put a minus sign before $x^3$ (since x<0$\Rightarrow x^3<0$?

Comment: @BetterWorld Who told that you **must** put a minus sign in front of an element to make it negative??

Comment: Why do we get 1 as a solution as well?

Comment: We get -1 as a solution, not 1.

Comment: @BetterWorld I seriously doubt you always learnt this: what is true in most cases that you always **thought so** . Don't be sorry, it happens to many, now just fix this notion.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^3 - x & if \, x \le 0,\\x^3+x &if \, 0 \le x. \end{cases}  $$

has one negative zero at $x = -1$ and a zero at $x = 0.$ you can see from the function definition that $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0.$  the graph of $y = f(x)$ has a cusp at $(0,0)$ which is also a local minimum.